# What does this "#" mean in this Clojure context?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reader, om

I stumbled upon the official Om example under "examples/mixins", there's a definition as this:

```
(def MyComponent (let [obj (om/specify-state-methods! (clj->js om/pure-methods))]
    (aset obj "mixins" #js [TestMixin])
    (js/React.createClass obj)))
```

What does "#js" mean? I couldn't find any Clojure documentation on symbol "#" when it's used in this way.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Om tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial):

> `#js {...}` and `#js [...]` is what is referred to as a reader literal. ClojureScript supports data literals for JavaScript via `#js`. `#js {...}` is for JavaScript objects:

```
#js {:foo "bar"}  ;; is equivalent to
#js {"foo" "bar"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, Diego. I indeed overlooked the tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

First of all [Om](https://github.com/swannodette/om) is a [Clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/) library. There are some differences between Clojure and Clojurescript, they are documented [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure).

`#js` is called a tagged literal, that comes from [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn), basically a tagged literal tells the reader how to parse the data, in the case of `#js` it tells the reader to parse the data as a `Javascript` object. Take a look [here](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2014/05/19/the-weird-and-wonderful-characters-of-clojure/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the article, Rodrigo.

Answer (score 0):

All dispatch reader macros begin with #. When you see this it means something special will happen at the moment the code is read, and that is no different with #js than with #( or #_ or even #{ for sets. In this case it tells the reader that what follows is a JavaScript literal.

More here: http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters